# Get OAuth 2.0 token via ACS

Tags: oauth-2.0, acs, windows-live-id, azure-acs

I have an application that understands OAuth 2.0 token (on passing a valid OAuth 2.0 token, it authenticates a user) returned by [Live ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx) .

This OAuth toke looks like -

"78wcH%2by1t6avE8zhVCzXQndK2zWJbCWvoZbSKfAduQuyQETUG2FtN5FOw%2bKaj5uCwUfuOS/2J35NvhDkZaaqoOzOVuoTYUDZgAACNzcJuSyBR21CAE9LpBrltj0PljQ76Hd9aJXW8x8DtRsKZvOn76PN69oGDzrGIjXXPIyCGDii9TYmP92kmh50B05qTqhdLiAXcluriQWuEMKONPUVazSmFN2BXZVW3NDdk3vkos8m68SXf%2"

Now I have another application which is based on Azure ACS mechanism. I can get SAML or SWT token from there.

Sample SWT tokens can be found [here](http://riccardocorradin.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/using-oauth-v2-to-request-a-swt-token-from-windows-azure/)

Is there any method I can convert the SAML/SWT tokens to the former OAuth 2.0 token?

Note: I tried fetching SWT tokens via OAuth v2-13 protocol, but this token is not validated by the service accepting OAuth token.

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

ACS doesnot expose any API which converts a SAML token to an OAuth 2.0 token.

The possible alternative is that on receiving a SAML token, break open the token, verify the authenticity of the user and successively, fetch OAuth token for the user using live id APIs.

It will definitely double the latency for your signin process.